# Center And Zoom function using ArcGIS API for JavaScript?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, zoom

I'm trying to insert x, and y coordinates manually through input text, and center the map and zoom it to that point. I have this code:

```
var x = $("#x").val();
var y = $("#y").val();
var point=new esri.geometry.Point(x, y, map.spatialReference);
map.centerAndZoom(point,6);
```

When executing this code, it gives me a blank page. What's wrong?
I also tried this code:

```
  map.graphics.clear();
  var xMin, yMin, xMax, yMax;
  var mp = new esri.geometry.Point;

  mp.x = $("#x").val();
  mp.y = $("#y").val();
  mp.spatialReference = map.spatialReference;
  var symbol = new esri.symbol.SimpleMarkerSymbol(esri.symbol.SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE_CROSS, 30, new esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol(esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID, new dojo.Color([255,0,0]), 1), new dojo.Color([0,255,0,0.25]));
  var graphic = new esri.Graphic(mp, symbol);
  xMin = mp.x-1000;
  yMin = mp.y-1000;
  xMax = mp.x+1000; 
  yMax = mp.y+1000;

  var newExtent = new esri.geometry.Extent();
  newExtent.xmin = xMin;
  newExtent.ymin = yMin;
  newExtent.xmax = xMax;
  newExtent.ymax = yMax;

  newExtent.spatialReference = map.spatialReference;

  map.setExtent(newExtent);
  map.graphics.add(graphic);
```

Also does not work. Any help??

Comment: do the X and Y match the spatial reference of the map?  sure they aren't transposed?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I tried different values for x and y, and the same happens, my spatial reference is 102100

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just finished doing something very similar so perhaps this will help you. I'm not using map.setExtent though (except as a fallback). Instead I'm using map.centerAndZoom. Right ***after*** I add the graphic, I have this bit of code. I'm thinking this may point you in the right direction (instead of maxZoom, you may be able to plug that zoom level 6 in?). One other difference is that I'm using a graphics layer ("esri/layers/GraphicsLayer") and adding the graphic to that instead of directly to map.graphics. Try adding this (after my comment line) after you add the graphic to the map.

**EDIT:** I do also have this line further up in the script.

```
var mp = webMercatorUtils.webMercatorToGeographic(evt.mapPoint);

graphicsLayer = new GraphicsLayer();  
graphicsLayer.add(graphic);  

map.addLayer(graphicsLayer);
// Add this bit of code after adding your graphic, 
if (graphic.geometry.type === 'point') {  
    maxZoom = map.getMaxZoom();  
    map.centerAndZoom(graphic.geometry, maxZoom - 1);  
} else {  
    map.setExtent(graphicsUtils.graphicsExtent([graphic]));        
} // end if
```

**EDIT:** I took out the second else per your commment. I was doing this nested inside a second if block that tests for the presence of a comma in a string entered by a user (lat, long) and the first if is testing for the index of the ",". I don't know what else you would need to do because this is working for me.

Comment: Thanks jbchurchill for your answer, I tried your code, and still didn't work. In your answer, you have tow else blocks, for one if statement, I removed the second one, and tried the code, the same happens

Comment: Odd. This is working for me. If you look at the console, what kind of error(s) are you getting other than just seeing a white page? Are you sure your coordinates are valid? What do you get with console.log(mp.x);

Comment: Well, now it is working, I just added this line, 
mp = esri.geometry.geographicToWebMercator(mp); no errors were on the console

Answer (score 1):

```
 if (shape == "Point") {
      map.centerAndZoom(features[0].geometry, 18);
 }
 else if (shape == "Line") {
     var extent = esri.graphicsExtent(features);
     if (extent) {
         $scope.map.setExtent(extent)
      }
 }
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me:

package.json:

```
"esri-loader": "^2.14.0",
"angular2-draggable": "^2.3.2",
```

component:

```
  async initializeMap() {
    try {
      // Load the modules for the ArcGIS API for JavaScript
      const [EsriMap, EsriMapView, Graphic, GraphicsLayer, TextSymbol, Point] = await loadModules([
        "esri/Map",
        "esri/views/MapView",
        "esri/Graphic",
        "esri/layers/GraphicsLayer",
        "esri/symbols/TextSymbol",
        "esri/geometry/Point"
      ]);
      this.Point = Point;
      this.Graphic = Graphic;
      this.TextSymbol = TextSymbol;

      // Configure the Map
      const mapProperties: esri.MapProperties = {
        basemap: this._basemap
      };

      const map: esri.Map = new EsriMap(mapProperties);

      this.graphicsLayer = new GraphicsLayer();
      map.add(this.graphicsLayer);

      // Initialize the MapView
      const mapViewProperties: esri.MapViewProperties = {
        container: this.mapViewEl.nativeElement,
        center: this._center,
        zoom: this._zoom,
        map: map
      };

      this._view = new EsriMapView(mapViewProperties);
      await this._view.when();
      return this._view;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("EsriLoader: ", error);
    }
  }


  setNewCenter(point: Point) {
    if (this._view && this._view.center) {
      this._view.center = new this.Point(point.latitude, point.longitude);
      this._view.zoom = 5;
    }
  }
```